# How to load user code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program which automatically generates a data structure from user-provided JSON code.  I also want to provide an option to allow users to write their own function to generate this data structure programmatically.  Is there a way for Python to load an arbitrary module by path and return that module's namespace so I can call the user's function from my program?

Example, I want something like the following:

```
def make(custom):
    if not custom:
        return helper('example.json')
    else:
        return load('path/to/user-script.py').make()  # this line here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import a named `.py` file as if it were a module by using `imp.load_source`; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path).

This is usually a pretty weird thing to do, but loading user hooks that don't live in the Python module hierarchy seem like an okay excuse.  :)

---

[This Python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue14551) claims that `load_source` is obsolete in Python 3, and advises the somewhat more cumbersome and less obvious invocation:

```
importlib.SourceFileLoader(name, path).load_module(name)
```

Comment: I saw that question actually, but I though that was for python 2 as imp.load_source isn't documented for 3, but I checked just now and it's still there though not documented.  Figures.  Here, have a cookie.

Comment: ah, it seems it's been obsoleted for 3.  updated answer with the new hotness